# SignalR can't find hub from external assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

i writing small web application, and want to use signalr to create push notifications, but when i am loading hubs from other assembly, nothing is happen.

here is my assembly locator, from other library which referenced to my asp.net mvc project

```
public class HubAssemblyLocator : IAssemblyLocator {

    public IList<Assembly> GetAssemblies() {


        IList<Assembly> allAsms = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().ToList();

        var executingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        var assemblyFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles( executingDirectory, "Application" );

        foreach ( var assemblyFile in assemblyFiles.Where( _ => _.EndsWith( ".dll" ) ) ) {

            var asm = Assembly.LoadFile( assemblyFile );

            if ( asm.GetTypes().Any( _ => _.BaseType == typeof( Hub ) ) ) {
                allAsms.Add( asm );
            }
        }

        return allAsms;
    }
}
```

Here my ApplicationStart Event in Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {

    protected void Application_Start() {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register( GlobalConfiguration.Configuration );
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters( GlobalFilters.Filters );
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes( RouteTable.Routes );
        InitializeRepositories.Initialize();



        var servicesPre = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.GetServices( typeof( IAssemblyLocator ) );

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true});

        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register( typeof( IAssemblyLocator ), () => new HubAssemblyLocator() );

        var servicesPost = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.GetServices(typeof (IAssemblyLocator));
    }
}
```

in this question this problem resolved, but in my situation is not work.

[SignalR IAssemblyLocator not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063891/signalr-iassemblylocator-override-not-firing)

And in my situation assembly locator not executed.

Update: Just register hubs before area and routes registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() should be called before RegisterRoutes(), but in your Application_Start it is called after. You also register HubAssemblyLocator after calling MapHubs(), but logically it should go before.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but main problem is HubAssemblyLocator not fired =)